# Moles example not working from Pex and Mole site

Tags: moles

I'm using the "Unit testing with Microsoft moles" document to learn moles found on the MS Pex and Moles website. I have stepped through the guide and found a number of issues that I cannot resolve. These issues have prevented me from running the examples.
By just coppying and pasting the code from Appendix A I have a number of errors.

1. In the class 'TestReader' the method 'LoadFile' is calling a static method 'ReadAllText' from FileSystem, but this isn't staticly defined in the class.
2. The class 'SIFileSystem' being used in the class testReaderTest is never defined anywhere and the method 'ReadAllTextString' from the clas 'SIFileSystem' is never defined as well. Does this class need to be defined by the programemr or is it autogenerated by the IDE. I see a partial example in the guide but no real clear directions on whether it should be creted or not. This is confusing!
3. In the method 'CheckValidFileWithMoles' in the class 'TestReaderTest' there is a object being staticly used named 'MFileSystem', what is this and is it a typo? Its being used twice.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are several problems in the documentation.  In regards to the issues you listed:

1.) You're correct, ReadAllText is an instance member.  You can just replace the line with:

```
var content = new FileSystem().ReadAllText(fileName);
```

2.) `SIFileSystem` is a stub type generated by the Moles framework.  If you didn't put `TestReader.cs`, `FileSystem.cs`, and `IFileSystem.cs` in their own project create a new one and move them.  In the test project, add a reference to the project with the other three files then right click on the reference and select the "Add Moles Assembly" option.

When you build, Moles will generate the stub and mole classes and you can then import the types by adding:

```
using StubsTutorial.Moles;
```

to `UnitTest1.cs`.

3.) `MFileSystem` is a mole type generated by Moles and will be included when you follow the steps above.  There's also another problem with the `CheckValidFileWithMoles` method though:

```
MFileSystem.ReadAllTextString = delegate(string f) { /* body omitted */ };
```

doesn't work.  If the `ReadAllText` method was static this would be correct but since it's an instance member the `MFileSystem` class doesn't include a corresponding static property.  To fix it we need to change that to use the static `AllInstances` property instead:

```
MFileSystem.AllInstances.ReadAllTextString = (@this, f) => { /* body omitted */ };
```

The way the `TestReader` class is written we have to mole it this way.  We could also add a constructor to the `TestReader` class to accept an instance of `IFileSystem` and pass an instance of `MFileSystem` to that constructor instead.

Hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: I concur. It is important to note the documentation is not written for the most recent release of Moles and Pex.